# Error occured while updating.. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, service, arguments

In my project i'm trying to parse XML pockets from one table to multiple tables, using those tables I will show values in the front end UI. After starting the Windows Service the XML pocket has been parsing from one table to multiple tables but one of the Stored Procedure is failed. In log file I got this message **"Error occured while updating the status of Ivr Call Data
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function *PROC_UPDATE_IVR_CALLDATA_STATUS* has too many arguments specified."**

My Stored Procedure *PROC_UPDATE_IVR_CALLDATA_STATUS*:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_UPDATE_IVR_CALLDATA_STATUS]
(
    @i_CallID               VARCHAR(50),    
    @i_AppID        VARCHAR(24),    
    @i_CallData             XML,
    @i_Status               CHAR(1),
    @i_ProcessStatus        VARCHAR(25),    
    @o_ErrorCode            int OUTPUT,
    @o_ErrorDescription     VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @o_ErrorCode=0
        SET @o_ErrorDescription='SUCCESS'

        IF Exists(SELECT CallID from TBL_CALLDATA_MASTER_BACKUP D               
                  Where D.CallID = @i_CallID 
                 )
        BEGIN         
                  UPDATE TBL_CALLDATA_MASTER_BACKUP
                  SET   [Status] = @i_Status,
                  ProcessStatus = @i_ProcessStatus 
                  Where CallID = @i_CallID 

        END 
        ELSE
        BEGIN

        INSERT INTO TBL_CALLDATA_MASTER_BACKUP( CallID,ApplicationID,  CallData,[Status], ProcessStatus)
        VALUES ( @i_CallID,@i_AppID,  @i_CallData, @i_Status,
            @i_ProcessStatus );
        END       

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH     
        SET @o_ErrorCode=ERROR_NUMBER()
        SET @o_ErrorDescription=ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
```

Method I'm using in the Service is:

```
public void UpdateCallDataStatus(Hashtable htCallDataStatusInfo)
        {
            int errorCode = 0;
            string errorDesc = string.Empty;

            object[] outParamList = new object[0];
            SqlDatabase sqlDb = new SqlDatabase(_connStr);
            List<SqlParameter> paramList = new List<SqlParameter>();

            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@i_CallID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200, ParameterDirection.Input, htCallDataStatusInfo["CALL_ID"]));
            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@i_SessionID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200, ParameterDirection.Input, htCallDataStatusInfo["SESSION_ID"]));
            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@i_ApplicationID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, htCallDataStatusInfo["APP_ID"]));
            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@i_CallDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50, ParameterDirection.Input, htCallDataStatusInfo["CALL_START_TIME"]));
            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@i_CallData", SqlDbType.Xml, 500000, ParameterDirection.Input, htCallDataStatusInfo["CALL_DATA"]));
            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@i_Status", SqlDbType.Char, 1, ParameterDirection.Input, htCallDataStatusInfo["STATUS"]));
            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@i_ProcessStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25, ParameterDirection.Input, htCallDataStatusInfo["PROCESS_STATUS"]));
            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@i_ProcessFailureReason", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000, ParameterDirection.Input, htCallDataStatusInfo["FAILURE_REASON"]));
            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@o_ErrorCode", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Output));
            paramList.Add(sqlDb.CreateParameter("@o_ErrorDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200, ParameterDirection.Output));

            sqlDb.ExecuteNonQuery("PROC_UPDATE_IVR_CALLDATA_STATUS", CommandType.StoredProcedure, paramList, out outParamList);
            errorCode = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(outParamList[0]));
            errorDesc = Convert.ToString(outParamList[1]);

            this.Response.ErrorCode = errorCode;
            this.Response.ErrorDescription = errorDesc;
        }
```

I don't know how to fix this issue. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing 10 parameters as command and only you are define 7 in your stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_UPDATE_IVR_CALLDATA_STATUS]
(
    @i_CallID               VARCHAR(50), 
    @i_AppID        VARCHAR(24), 
    @i_CallData             XML,
    @i_Status               CHAR(1),
    @i_ProcessStatus        VARCHAR(25), 
    @o_ErrorCode            INT OUTPUT,
    @o_ErrorDescription     VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT
)
```

define all output parameters in stored procedure that you are passed by sql cmd

like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_UPDATE_IVR_CALLDATA_STATUS]
(
    @i_CallID               VARCHAR(50), 
    @i_ApplicationID        VARCHAR(24), 
    @i_CallData             XML,
    @i_Status               CHAR(1),
    @i_ProcessStatus        VARCHAR(25), 
    @o_ErrorCode            INT OUTPUT,
    @o_ErrorDescription     VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT,
    @i_SessionID            VARCHAR(200),
    @i_CallDateTime         DATETIME,
    @i_ProcessFailureReason VARCHAR(1000)            
)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. Your logic is correct. I have one doubt, I have defined Application Id as `@i_AppID` in SP but in Service method I have defined as `@i_ApplicationID`. Will this create a problem?

Comment: It will not map, c # to stored procedure parameter mapping requires the same name in both side , otherwise it shows error

Comment: Why I'm asking this is, that problem still existing. Before changing the SP, the parser was worked correctly but after adding all the variables in SP, the parser itself not working.

Comment: Think if we have two parameters with same datatype and we are passing these two to our sp with different name then how our sp will understand which one is corresponding to which . so the naming is importent

Comment: +one  and Thanks for reaming me that , actually i did't notice you are giving different name in sp